# Let's encrypt 502 bad gateway docker

Tags: nginx, docker, lets-encrypt

I tried to set an nginx proxy with let's encrypt, all dockerized, by following this tutorial : 
http://www.automationlogic.com/using-lets-encrypt-and-docker-for-automatic-ssl/

The problem is that my application exposes port 1337 instead of 80, and I can't change this for now.

Do someone know how I could tell nginx to listen on the app container's at 1337?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at that tutorial and the available source code, the nginx configuration files are using a placeholder **_APPLICATION_PORT_** which gets replaced with the nginx docker container's environment variable $APP_PORT_80_TCP_PORT in it's start.sh script.  It appears that specific environment variable would need to be added to the docker-compose.yml file:

```
nginx:
  environment:
    - APP_PORT_80_TCP_PORT=1337
```

You would also need to make sure that the docker-compose.yml has the correct port for your application (if docker-compose is launching your application container) so docker exposes the correct port.

Hope that helps

Comment: Ouch, noob mistake, I mis read the script.
Thanks for the answer !